# Dynamic variable name in Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

I have a number of lists with names, that were created by appending `ec2_public_dns_name` to `seeds_`

Like this: `seeds_ec2-50-8-1-43.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`

I need in config for each host to access it's list and loop over it.
I try to do it like this:

In playbook assign to new variable:

```
- name: Seeds provision
  set_fact:
    seeds: "seeds_{{ec2_public_dns_name}}"
```

And than in config use it:

```
{% for seed in seeds %}
{{seed.name ~ ","}}
{% endfor %}
```

But it seems like `seeds` in config file is just text, I can't access list elements.
How can this be done?

Comment: I don't really understand what you try to do. In your task you define a string. Do you want to loop over all your involved hosts in the config file?

Comment: I try to form variable name dynamically and then get value of this variable (it is set in another imported file)

Answer (score 1):

Task:

```
- set_fact:
    seeds: "seeds_{{ec2_public_dns_name}}
```

creates text variable `seeds` which value is `seeds_ec2-50-8-1-43.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`.

If you want `seeds` to be list that you will iterate, you need to add `seeds_{{ec2_public_dns_name}}` to `seeds` list:

```
- set_fact:
    seeds: [] # define seeds as empty list
- set_fact:
    seeds: "{{seeds + ['seeds_' + ec2_public_dns_name]}}"
```

But this will add to array `seeds` one element. Probably you have `ec2_public_dns_names` that is a list of public DNS values for your hosts:

```
ec2_public_dns_names: 
  - ec2-50-8-1-43.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
  - ec2-50-8-2-43.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
  - ...
```

With such list, you can create list of seeds with following task:

```
- set_fact:
    seeds: "{{seeds + ['seeds_' + item]}}"
  with_items: "{{ec2_public_dns_names}}"
```